# Can not compare variables in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

My template code:

```
    <select name="channelChoice" id="channelChoice" class="choiceBox">
    <option value="0">Chose your channel</option>
    {% if channels %}
        {% for ch in channels %}
            {% if ch.id == default_channel_id %}
                <option class="channel-choice" value="{{ ch.id }}"  selected="selected" >{{ ch.title }}</option>
            {% else %}
                <option class="channel-choice" value="{{ ch.id }}" >{{ ch.title }}</option>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</select>
```

My python code:

```
def index(request):
channels = models.Channel.objects.filter(activated=True).order_by('title')
default_channel_id = request.GET.get('channel_id', False)
if not default_channel_id:
    default_channel_id = 1
return render(request, 'epgadmin/index.html', {'channels': channels, 'default_channle_id': default_channel_id})
```

I passed default_channel_id with value is 1, and list of channels contain a channel with exactly id is 1. But if clause is never reached!

Comment: Correct the spelling of default_channel_id in this line: "return render(request, 'epgadmin/index.html', {'channels': channels, 'default_channle_id': default_channel_id})" .

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `models` in the query:

```
from models import Channel
channels = Channel.objects.filter(activated=True).order_by('title')
```

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: I don't know why are you use `model` like that. You did not `import` it?check this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/

Comment: You can print your `Channel` and your `default_channel_id` in views to see it if what you want.

Comment: This `models` is a file contain list of my `model` extended from `django.db.models`. I imported it at top of file

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the variable that you pass to template: default_channle_id

Comment: What is mean of typo? Did you mean type?

Comment: You need `default_channel_id` but you passed `default_channle_id`. That's a typo which means misspelling.